# Printing in ReactJS

Tags: node.js, reactjs, electron

How do I print(printer) a DIV in my app component in react ? I have a DIV=(badgeContainer) inside which I have added a few shapes, text and Images, now i would like to print the elements inside the DIV=(badgeContainer). Is there a package which would help me do this in react ? Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: By print, do you mean display on the screen (the DOM) or print to a printer or to the console?

Comment: To a printer and I am using electron as well. So if you have a solution using electron even that is appreciated.

Comment: Create you own component, avoid using npm package until unless  your component is complicated

Comment: I used the electron code to achieve this, [webContents.print](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/web-contents.md#contentsprintoptions) did the trick for me.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using the useRef hook and window.(open & print & close).

```
import React from "react";
export const Printable = () => {
  const printableAreaRef = React.useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);
  const handlePrintClick = () => {
    const w = window.open();
    if (printableAreaRef.current?.innerHTML) {
      w?.document.write(printableAreaRef.current.innerHTML);
      w?.print();
    }
    w?.close();
  };
  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={handlePrintClick}>Click To Print</button>
      <div ref={printableAreaRef}>
        I want to print this
      </div>
    </>
  );
};
```

Comment: please find complete printing solution in react  with example here, https://codesanitize.com/react-printing-made-easy-a-powerful-method/

Answer (score 0):

There's several libraries you can use for this. I have used https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF and it's great.

Comment: Thanks for the solution.

Answer (score 0):

you can you this package :
[**ReactToPrint - Print React components in the browser**](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-to-print)

I use it and it can handle print for you